# Android - ShareActionProvider always open

Tags: android

I want to allow users to share article from my news android app. So, I've add the button in my Toolbar like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context="com.compafone.app.news">


<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"
    android:title="Partager"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>


</menu>
```

This in my OnCreate method content:

```
private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_news);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_revert);

    [...]

    Intent shareintent=new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareintent.setType("text/plain");
    shareintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);

    // Add data to the intent, the receiving app will decide what to do with it.
    shareintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Some subject line");
    shareintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Body");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareintent, "How do you want to share ?"));

}
```

And methods for the ShareActionProider:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu resource
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_news, menu);

    // Get the menu item.
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);
    // Get the provider and hold onto it to set/change the share intent.
    mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(menuItem);

    // Attach an intent to this ShareActionProvider.  You can update this at any time,
    // like when the user selects a new piece of data they might like to share.
    mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(createShareIntent());

    // This line chooses a custom shared history xml file. Omit the line if using
    // the default share history file is desired.
    mShareActionProvider.setShareHistoryFileName("custom_share_history.xml");

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

private Intent createShareIntent() {
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
    shareIntent.setType("image/*");

    // For a file in shared storage.  For data in private storage, use a ContentProvider.
    //Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(getFileStreamPath(""));
    //shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    return shareIntent;
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            //  The Intents Fairy has delivered us some data!
            String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
            // Handle successful scan
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // Handle cancel
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the Share Box is displays automatically at the beginning of my activity. And the button does not works.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the solution ...

- Delete this from OneCreate:

  ```
   startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareintent, "How do you want to share ?"));
  ```
- Delete this from XML

  ```
  app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider"
  ```
- Delete this from OneCreateMenuOption:

  ```
  mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(createShareIntent());
  mShareActionProvider.setShareHistoryFileName("custom_share_history.xml");
  ```
- Add this to OnOptionItemSelected:

  ```
   case R.id.menu_item_share:
   startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareintent, "How do you want to share ?"));
   return true;
  ```

Work for me. (I think that only work with AppCompat V7, not work for classic android.widget.ShareActionProvider)